# Find minimum value for all sites

Tags: r

In the df below, there are two sites with different depths. I am trying to find the minimum temperature by each site but when I subset by `min` I get only one value (the minimum for the whole df). I tried `by=site` but I still only get one value. How can I get a minimum value for each site?

```
 site <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

 temp <- c(1, 0.8, -1, -2, -2.5, -3, -2.3, -2.2, -2, -1.5, 1.2, 1.1, -0.6, -1, -1.8, -2.3, -2.5, -2.2, -2, -1)

depth <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 16, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(site, temp, depth))

minT <- subset(df, temp == min(temp), by = site)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr::summarise` you could do:

```r
df <- data.frame(site, temp, depth)

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df |>
  summarise(min_temp = min(temp), .by = site)
#>   site min_temp
#> 1    1     -3.0
#> 2    2     -2.5
```

or using `aggregate`:

```
df |> 
  aggregate(
    temp ~ site, FUN = min
  )
#>   site temp
#> 1    1 -3.0
#> 2    2 -2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers by [@stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78052450/12158757) with `summarise` and `aggregate` are very good options to your question, and here is another thing you could try, say, `by(...)`

```
> with(df, by(temp, site, min))
site: 1
[1] -3
------------------------------------------------------------
site: 2
[1] -2.5
```